# Swift 4: Checking if week, month, 2 months, etc. has passed since initial launch using Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I'm trying to include timers so that a button appears a week, a month, 2 months, etc. after the initial launch date of the app.

I've used [Date.addingTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval) (see code below), but it doesn't seem as effective for longer periods of time (week/months). The Swift documentation recommends using Calendar, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        if installedDate == nil {
            installedDate = Date()
            let timer = Calendar.current

            Button1.isHidden = true
            Button2.isHidden = true
            Button3.isHidden = true
        }

        else {
            print("Not first run")
            print(installedDate!)

            let Button1Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(604800)      //for after 1 week
            let Button2Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(2592000)     //for after 1 month
            let Button3Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(5184000)     //for after 2 months


            if installedDate == Button1Date {
                Button1.isHidden = false
            }
            if installedDate == Button2Date {
                Button2.isHidden = false
            }
            if installedDate == Button3Date {
                Button.isHidden = false
            }

        }

    }

    var installedDate: Date? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "installedDateKey") as? Date
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "installedDateKey")
        }
    }
```

What is a more efficient way of comparing the launch date to the expected date I need?

Comment: Is this an action you want to happen exactly at the second a month has passed whether the user has the app in the foreground or not or an action that you want to happen the first time the user opens the app after a month has passed?

Comment: As @bsod mentioned, your problem is that you're comparing dates in milliseconds. If you want to do that, you need to add them to `installedDate`, not `Date()` as otherwise this will next to never work.

Comment: @bsod Yes, it is an action I want to happen exactly after a month has passed. Every time they open the app, it’ll check whether a month has passed since the installedDate. My next step is to include a notification that lets them know that they have a new button to look at, which I’m not sure how to do either.

Comment: @Wheeeeeecode Check my answer, I think I fixed your problem.

Comment: @Wheeeeeecode, if you didn't notice, I updated my answer to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you want a button to display if they have had the app for more than a certain amount of time. If that is the case, I've written some code that will be helpful to you:

```
let timeSinceInstalled = -(installedDate ?? Date()).timeIntervalSinceNow

Button1.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 604800
Button2.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 2592000
Button3.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 5184000
```

You can actually replace most of the code inside of your `viewDidLoad()` function, even the part where you check if `installedDate == nil`. Here is your updated code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let timeSinceInstalled = -(installedDate ?? Date()).timeIntervalSinceNow
    Button1.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 604800
    Button2.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 2592000
    Button3.isHidden = timeSinceInstalled < 5184000
}

var installedDate: Date? {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "installedDateKey") as? Date
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "installedDateKey")
    }
}
```

If you want to set the title to "You have none available" when the button should not be clickable, here is the code for that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let timeSinceInstalled = -(installedDate ?? Date()).timeIntervalSinceNow
    setTitle(Button1, timeSinceInstalled < 604800)
    setTitle(Button2, timeSinceInstalled < 2592000)
    setTitle(Button3, timeSinceInstalled < 5184000)
}

func setTitle(_ button: UIButton, _ statement: Bool) {
    button.setTitle(statement ? "You have none available" : "Click me", for: .normal)
    button.isEnabled = !statement
}

var installedDate: Date? {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "installedDateKey") as? Date
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "installedDateKey")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted the screen these buttons appear on to say "You have none available" until the first timer has passed, how would I add that?